# .Net Core WebApp API Endpoints don't work once deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, api, .net-core

I'm having an issue with deploying a WebApp / API to Azure.

When I run it locally on localhost:44385//api/user/getuser/1, it returns the JSON for that user,
once deployed to an App Service on Azure, it starts returning a 404.

Its running on the free version as its for a uni assignment.
I've spent hours poking around and reading, and cant seem to find where i've gone wrong in the setup.
Hoping someone might of had a similar issue.

Comment: Are you using kestrel or? could you post the server's ip configuration?

Comment: It's just running within an App Service, then added it as a remote from Visual Studio.

Comment: I will add - I can get it to ping a standard controller and return a view, but the API Controllers are BaseControllers with [ApiController] attached to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure the server's routing rules are correct and that it's not looking in the directory structure?

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/url-route-overview#:~:text=In%20this%20article&text=URL%20Path%20Based%20Routing%20allows,to%20different%20backend%20server%20pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/url-route-overview#:%7E:text=In%20this%20article&text=URL%20Path%20Based%20Routing%20allows,to%20different%20backend%20server%20pools).

Answer (score 0):

**Please verify below points:**

1. That the Connection String of DB is correctly picked up by your Web API/it's correctly setup and configured.
2. If the DB and table/collection is present when you query and if not then you are creating it through your code.
3. If your data is present at the right place *(User with ID = 1 in DB and collection/table you are querying)*.
4. If your code is not throwing 404 incorrectly (even in positive scenarios).

Comment: I can confirm 2-4, when i run the App through VS, it pulls all the data correctly. I'm only getting the issue once its deployed to azure.

Could you point me in the right direction as far as the checklist for the Connection string once deployed?
I've got it listen in the App Services connection strings, as well as within the source code (for now).

Comment: Check this out to setup Configuration: https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-and-read-connection-string-in-appsettings-json/